# how to use php exec function inside cakephp mvc framework to call a php script from cake's webapplication

Tags: php, cakephp, exec

I have a webportal developed in cakephp framework accessible from webhost.For certain fields to update in realtime it requires a script to be called in php which inturn calls a python script.The php scripts works well when executed on console and returns the desired result.Now i want to integrate that script working on console with my web portal(frontend) so that people can view it on the portal without manually executing the file on linux terminal console(backend).How to integrate the two?

Comment: you can call external scripts just as you would do in PHP. This is nothing to do with CakePHP

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

(A) Create a link to the PHP script just as you would link to and html page (just .php instead of .html or .htm)

(B) Change your HTML extension to .php and place the PHP script directly into your existing code.

I'm sure there are other ways as well, though these seem to be the easiest. Hope this helps.